# Finding polar coordinates as 2 integrals

Tags: calculus

[image: question]

In question 2, how to do figure if i have to write it as 2 integrals integral. I think it is because we have 2 formulas which means 2 $r$'s? but how do i get the $\theta$ range for each one?

[image]

basically how do we get the $\theta$ of R2

Comment: The number of regions doesn't change just because you put a different coordinate grid on top of it. So if there is a single region in Cartesian coordinates, there is a single region in polar.

Comment: @Arthur in question 1 for dxdy we got 2 regions while for dydx we had 1 region

Comment: The number of regions doesn't change. Period. Now, whether it is most productive to split an integral into two integrals, that's an entirely different story.

Comment: ah so that what it is called let me edit my post then

Comment: Just "write as two integrals", or something like that. As to how to identify that that's the way to go, it has nothing to do with the number of inequalities, and everything to do with the actual shape of the region. Have you drawn it, seen what it looks like?

Comment: yes i did draw it